# Joining 2 dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have 2 dictionaries as follows

```
Dictionary<string,int> (values are unique as well)
{"xyz", 123}
{"abc", 456}

Dictionary<string,CustomObject>
{"xyz", instanceOfCustomObject1}
{"abc", instanceOfCustomObject2}
```

How do I join these 2 so that I get the following:

```
Dictionary<int,CustomObject>
{123, instanceOfCustomObject1}
{456, instanceOfCustomObject2}
```

I tried `dictionary1.Join(dictionary2, x=>x.Key, y=>y.Key,...)` but 'am blocked since I don't know how to project them out into the desired form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would need more than just a `Join()`.  Pair that up with a call to `ToDictionary()`.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary1 = ..;
Dictionary<string, CustomObject> dictionary2 = ...;
var dict = dictionary1.Join(dictionary2, d1 => d1.Key, d2 => d2.Key,
                            (d1, d2) => new { Key = d1.Value, Value = d2.Value })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate -- I don't think Linq gains you much here:

```
public Dictionary<int, CustomObject> Combine(Dictionary<string, int> first, Dictionary<string, CustomObject> second)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<int, CustomObject>();
    foreach (string key in first.Keys)
        if (second.ContainsKey(key))
            result.Add(first[key], second[key]);
    return result;
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
    foreach (string key in first.Keys.Union(second.Keys))
        result.Add(first[key], second[key]);
```